# DateTime format in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I have a simple problem: I want to write the date in an asp:label in the following format:
MMM dd, yyyy
I tried this:

```
lblDate.Text = System.DateTime.Today.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");
```

the result is: "okt. 12, 2012"

1. I want to remove the dot from it.
2. The month's name should begin with a capital letter.

the right format: "Okt 12, 2012"

how can I do this?

Comment: What culture are you running under?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [AbbreviatedMonthNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviatedmonthnames.aspx) property for this:

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = ci.DateTimeFormat;
dtfi.AbbreviatedMonthNames = new string[] 
{ 
  "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", 
  "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", 
  "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "" 
}; 

lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy", dtfi);
```

Then output will be `Okt 12, 2012`

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.ToString()` formats the date according to the rules set out in the current culture. You can change it manually using the technique shown by @naspinski, but other users of your application may get different results, depending on their culture-specific settings. For instance, some cultures use a dot as a date separator, as in "12.10.2012". You can change your regional settings in Windows control panel to format how you like.

Answer (score 1):

Manual way to do this:

```
string dt System.DateTime.Today.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")Replace(".","");
if(dt.length>0) dt = dt.SubString(0,1).ToUpper() + dt.SubString(1, dt.Length - 1);
lblDate.Text = dt;
```